# Getting canvas base64 from front to back in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html5-canvas

He there, i'm trying to get my canvas data on server part to analyze it.
I have my js on mouse button up that saves base64 data in hidden input on page

```
var src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

var rowCount = parseInt($("#total").val());
rowCount++;
$("#total").val(rowCount);
var html = '';
html += '<div id="inputRow">';
html += '<input type="hidden" name="[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].line" value="' + (src) + '"  />';
html += '</div>';

$('#newRow').append(html);
```

Aftet this i need to trigger somehow my c#

Maybe there is more correct way to do this? Or can i trigger OnPost() method from js?